# Make sure the path to the Android SDK is correct

Tags: python, kivy, ubuntu-18.04, buildozer

```
koushik@koushik-HP-Notebook:~$ p4a apk
[WARNING]: $ANDROIDNDKVER is deprecated and no longer necessary, the        
value you set is ignored
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 28
[ERROR]:   Build failed: Could not find `android` or `sdkmanager` 
binaries in Android SDK
[INFO]:    Instructions: Make sure the path to the Android SDK is 
correct
```

I have tried millions of time but this error comes up and I am pretty sure that I have set the paths properly, however any suggestion is strongly welcomed.

Comment: How have you informed python-for-android of the Android SDK location?

Answer (score 3):

In the

> p4a documentation

it is not clearly stated how to put the path, sorry for that.

Do this, dont include the full sdk directory path, instead omit it. For example if your path for your sdk is `export ANDROIDSDK="/home/kivy/Desktop/tools"` omit the 'tools'. this should now work with `export ANDROIDSDK="/home/kivy/Desktop/"`